# Error on Android Studio, while compiling: INSERT INTO Table doesn't exist?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, sql-insert

While I am doing a project, I need help for DB browser helper, where I do this

```
 CREATE TABLE `OrderDetailID` (
    `ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `ProductId` TEXT,
    `ProductName`   TEXT,
    `Quantity`  TEXT,
    `Price` TEXT,
    `Discount`  TEXT
);
```

But when I want to add cart on my app it crashes and my logcat shows this:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: OrderDetail (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('02','COCONUT PAO','1','1000','null');
```

And the error shows on my Database.java class on

```
public void addToCart(Order order) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
            order.getProductId(),
            order.getProductName(),
            order.getQuantity(),
            order.getPrice(),
            order.getDiscount());

    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

And the FoodDetail.java

```
btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                foodId,
                currentfood.getName(),
                numberButton.getNumber(),
                currentfood.getPrice(),
                currentfood.getDiscountmenuId()
        ));

        Toast.makeText(FoodDetail.this, "Added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

After doing a lot of search I didn't find any answer of this.

For your information, here is my getCarts() method on Database.java class

```
public List<Order> getCarts() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = {"ProductId", "ProductName", "Quantity", "Price", "Discount"};
    String sqlTable = "OrderDetail";

    qb.setTables(sqlTable);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);

    final List<Order> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            result.add(new Order(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductId")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductName")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Quantity")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Price")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Discount"))

            ));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In the `CREATE TABLE` query, you name the table `OrderDetailID`, but in the `INSERT` query you use `OrderDetail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `OrderDetailID`, but you trying to insert table `OrderDetail`.